# Django: How to show an admin user message if correction was made during model save?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have an app, and am wanting to do some automatic corrections to geometry (GeoDjango with PostGIS) rather than simply reject the save operation, since the corrections are being done after the data is committed to the database through the "MakeValid" database operation.

I would like to inform the admin user that the model was corrected and to verify their changed geometry, and this is where I am running into trouble.  I am attempting the "MakeValid" through an additional query in the model's "save" method after the initial save has completed, but it appears that I can only get the message to show if I move that logic into the admin logic overriding "save_model" to call "obj.save()" and then do my post-processing.  Is there a better way to pass information back to the admin view from the model save?

Comment: ModelAdmin class have two methods: `response_add()`, `response_change()` . These method called after save_mode() method. You can override it to change the behavior. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add